# Stata interaction term is zero or there is no number

Tags: output, stata, zero, interaction

I am asked to do the following question:
You suspect that the effect of being athletic on the quality of sleep depends on the
gender of the individual. Modify your previous model to test such hypothesis. What is
the effect of (i) being a male athlete (compared with a male non-athlete) and being (ii)
a female athlete (compared with a female non-athlete) on sleep quality, and (iii) how
does being a male change the impact of being athlete on sleep quality?

However I have problems with the interpretation of my graph.

For the question above my line of code is:
reg Sleepefficiency i.athletic i.sex athletic##sex

The line of code is adequate so that is not where my problem is. However in the table outcome i see 0's and sometimes no numbers. I have googled it as to what it means and I am still struggling. I am asking if anyone can help with the interpretation. Thank you so much in advance.

This is my interpretation so far:
As the  observations change of a non-male athletic to a male athletic unit, cetiris paribus, sleep efficiency increases by 1.035 units. As the observations change of a female athletic to a  non-female athletic unit.....

I have included the output table as well.

Comment: This seems off-topic here. It's more about statistical advice than a specific, explicit problem in Stata programming.  In any case it's about an assignment and so also off-topic on Statalist and unlikely to get far on Cross Validated.